# Reading the XML values using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

what is the best way of reading xml file using linq and the below code you will see that, I have three different loops and I feel like its not elegant or do I have options to retrofit the below code?

```
public static void readXMLOutput(Stream stream)
       {  
           XDocument xml = new XDocument();
           xml = LoadFromStream(stream); 

           var header = from p in xml.Elements("App").Elements("Application") 
                       select p;

           foreach (var record in header)
           {
               string noym = record.Element("nomy").Value;
               string Description = record.Element("Description").Value;
               string Name = record.Element("Name").Value;
               string Code = record.Element("Code").Value; 
           }

           var appRoles = from q in xml.Elements("App").Elements("Application").Elements("AppRoles").Elements("Role")
                        select q;

           foreach (var record1 in appRoles)
           {
               string Name = record1.Element("Name").Value;
               string modifiedName = record1.Element("ModifiedName").Value; 
           }

           var memeber = from r in xml.Elements("App").Elements("Application").Elements("AppRoles").Elements("Role").Elements("Members")
                          select r;

           foreach (var record2 in memeber)
           {

               string ExpirationDate = record2.Element("ExpirationDate").Value;
               string FullName = record2.Element("FullName").Value;                
           }


        }
```

UPDATED:

```
 foreach (var record in headers)
            {
                ..............
                string Name1 = record.Attribute("Name").Value;
                string UnmodifiedName = record.Attribute("UnmodifiedName").Value;

                string ExpirationDate = record.Attribute("ExpirationDate").Value;
                string FullName = record.Attribute("FullName").Value; 
                ...............
            }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Linq instead of simply deserializing it into a class?

Comment: @Mark: there is no reason to use Linq and if you have a better way please let me know.

Comment: @dtb: it reads the xml from input stream... its very simple nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not work precisely in your case depending on the xml structure.  Play around with it.  Try it using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
var applications = from p in xml.Descendants("Application") 
             select new { Nomy = p.Element("nomy").Value
                        , Description = p.Element("Description").Value 
                        , Name = p.Element("Name").Value
                        , Code = p.Element("Code").Value
             };

var appRoles = from r in xml.Descendants("Role")
               select new { Name = r.Element("Name").Value
                          , ModifiedName = r.Element("ModifiedName").Value
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that your actual code ? All those string variables you are assigning in the foreach loops only have a scope of one iteration of the loop. They are created and destroyed each time.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a hierarchical query.

```
var headers =
  from header in xml.Elements("App").Elements("Application")  
  select new XElement("Header",
    new XAttribute("noym", header.Element("nomy").Value),
    new XAttribute("Description", header.Element("Description").Value),
    new XAttribute("Name", header.Element("Name").Value),
    new XAttribute("Code", header.Element("Code").Value),
    from role in header.Elements("AppRoles").Elements("Role")
    select new XElement("Role",
      new XAttribute("Name", role.Element("Name").Value),
      new XAttribute("ModifiedName", role.Element("ModifiedName").Value),
      from member in role.Elements("Members")
      select new XElement("Member",
        new XAttribute("ExpirationDate", member.Element("ExpirationDate").Value),
        new XAttribute("FullName", member.Element("FullName").Value)
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: where does the Header come from?
select new XElement("Header",

Comment: header is introduced in the line above that... from header in

Comment: i have udpate my question, there are two problems in your solution
1) it does not loop
2) it does not read the ExpirationDate or FullName...

Comment: Why is not looping a problem? 
it reads the expiriation date and full name in the last line.